# cannot decode kubernetes secrets with base64

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I'm trying to get secrets with `kubectl` with:

```
kubectl get secrets/postgresql -n my-namespace -o=go-template=='{{index .data "postgresql-password" }}'
```

it returns the correct value ( I get the same result with lens )

But when I do:

```
kubectl get secrets/postgresql -n my-namespace -o=go-template=='{{index .data "postgresql-password" }}' | base64 -d
```

I get:

```
base64: invalid input
```

But Lens can decode it easily. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check command :

```
kubectl get secrets/postgresql -n my-namespace -o=go-template=='{{index .data "postgresql-password" }}'
```

if you see base64 string it is good. But also you can see "=" in the start and the end of this string.

Just try to run the following :

```
kubectl get secrets/postgresql -n my-namespace -o=go-template='{{index .data "postgresql-password" }}' | base64 -d
```

Comment: my bad, it was a typo error ! Tx !!!